# Does averaging affect statistics?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, mean

I have an array that represents client's bills for a certain period of time. Each client has several values. I need to group data by week or month and calculate mean and variance. However, I have a question, is it correct and is there any difference at all, if I just take an average before calculating the statistics. I mean instead of getting 12 numbers for each month for the first used I get just one value, the average of these numbers. i understand that there's no difference for the mean, but what about variance? It changes a little bit in a short term, but in what about the long term?

Thank you

Comment: It does matter, it also matters for the mean, if you do not have an equal number of bills per month.

Comment: @user2974951 I pretty much understand that, but still cannot explain to myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following data. You can imagine the two groups as two months, and the two rows as two bills.

| Group A | Group B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

The overall average is equal to $2.5$. The mean of A is $2$, the mean of B is $3$. The mean of $2$ and $3$ is $2.5$, which is the same as the overall average.

Now consider the following data, which has the same exact values, but is grouped differently.

| Group A | Group B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
|  | 3 |
|  | 4 |

The overall mean is still the same. The mean of A is $1$, the mean of B is $3$, and the mean of $1$ and $3$ is $2$, which is not equal to the overall mean anymore.

A similar argument can be made for variance, since you are using the mean when estimating the variance.

**Edit:** how is all this relevant for your problem? Let's assume the following data for a given client.

|  | Month 1 | Month 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Car bill | 100 | 120 |
| Dentist bill |  | 700 |
| Trash bill | 30 | 20 |

What you choose to calculate now depends on your research question.

Suppose you are interested in the average bill price for this client, then you would calculate a simple average of all the bills, which is  $194$, and the standard deviation is $\approx 286$.

Suppose instead you were interested in the average monthly bill for this client, then you would first calculate an average for each month, and then average these. The mean of month 1 is $65$, the mean of month 2 is $280$, the mean of these two is $172.5$, the standard deviation is $\approx 152$.

Conclusion: 1) the mean will not be the same if you have a different number of bills per month, 2) the variance/SD can vary greatly based on how you group your data.

Comment: I didn't take groups into account. Instead, I took mean of all values and received same values. Thank you.

Comment: But if we take the mean of group A and the mean of group B, the overall mean will be the same. That's what I 'm talking about.

Comment: You would have to take the sample-weighted average of the groups to get the correct overall mean.

Comment: Still confused.

Comment: What are you confused about?

Comment: @user2974951 each client has a few bills. His or her own bills. I am not supposed to shuffle groups as you did. If we take the mean of group A and the mean of group B, the overall mean will be the same. Thus, averaging will not affect the result. Variance will be biased, but not so much.

Comment: @user12628549 See my edit.